# Defining #1^#2 as \overset{#2}{#1} for some characters

Tags: math-mode, macros

When I write math in `xelatex`, I like notation such as:

```
$x \overset{ℝ}{+} y$  
$x \overset{f}{↦} y $  
$x \overset{(1)}{=} y$
```

However, as I type things like this so often, I would like to type it faster, and to keep the source code better readable (in the sense of quick scanning the code). I thought about three things, from which I don't how to do it (or if it is possible):

1. Defining `#1^#2` as `\overset{#2}{#1}` when `#1∈{+,↦,=,→}` and maybe more
2. Defining `#1^^#2` as `\overset{#2}{#1}` for all `#1`
3. Defining `#1↖#2` as `\overset{#2}{#1}` for all `#1`

I prefer option 1, but I'm not sure if this is possible. I think it should be possible as `\sum`, `\int` and `\prod` already act in this way.

Comment: You can do `#1` with the same process as `\sum`, `\int` and so on but it would be tricky to sort out the cases where those characters (especially `+`) is not used as a relation or binary symbol. Options 2 and 3 are nearly impossible because TeX would have to look back which it usually doesn’t.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel But it does also look back for `^` and `_` right ? I get the result that I wanted with $\mathop{#1}^{#2}$, could I do something as define #1 as \mathop{#1} for #1∈{+,↦,=,→} ?

Comment: @Kasper No, it doesn't look back in those cases. But `\mathop{+}^{\mathbb{R}}` would give wrong spacing around the symbol.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you really want this; however, here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineoversetchar}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \kasper_define_overset_char:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kasper_define_overset_char:n
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cn { kasper_#1_active: }
   {
    \peek_catcode_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_math_superscript_token
     {
      \kasper_overset:nn { #1 }
     }
     {
      \use:c { kasper_#1_inactive: }
     }
   }
  \char_set_active_eq:Nc #1 { kasper_#1_active: }
  \AtBeginDocument
   {
    \cs_new:cx { kasper_#1_inactive: } { \Umathcharnum \the\Umathcodenum`#1 }
    \char_set_mathcode:nn { `#1 } { "8000 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kasper_overset:nn
 {
  \overset{#2}{\use:c { kasper_#1_inactive: }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineoversetchar{+,↦,=,→}

\begin{document}

$x ℝ^{+} y$

$x ↦^f y ↦ z$

$x →^f y → z$

$x =^{(1)} y = z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that a special character used in a superscript (or subscript) should be in braces.